# How to get the path to Android's Download folder using C++?

Tags: android, c++, path, download

In my C++ Android game I'm trying to access and load files from the Download folder, so people can download each others mods. Is that possible, and how do I get the path to the Download folder?

Comment: Dont know how to get that in C++ but until you know it you can use /storage/emuated/0/Download.

Comment: Or use JNI to call a Java method that returns the path as a string.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work (even when I fixed the typo in emuated to emulated!). I've listed the permissions:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

are there other permissions the app needs? Or does Android not let apps read from the Download folder maybe?

Comment: All depends on the used Android version. And if the files are not created/downloaded by your app you will not be able to list them from Android 11+ on.

Comment: Sorry for the missing l. You will also not be able to open/read files that do not belong to your app.

Comment: By "not be able to list them" do you mean read them?